# Pinescript BOX.NEW — Right shift of X numbers of bars

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to have a box’s right side shifted of 50 bars to the right from the current bar. I achieved this shift using `line.new` ([the blue line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zbaPp.png)), but despite having similar properties with `box.new`, I can’t figure out how to achieve it.

I tried to use `last_bar_index + 50` in the `right` argument of `box.set_rightbottom`, unsuccessfully.

With the current parameters, the code shows no box at all.

Please find my code below. Box's code is at the very bottom.

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Box TEST', overlay=true)

//Periods to display
currDay = input(1)

//Lines
var line cdo_line = na 
var line cdh_line = na  
var line cdl_line = na  

var cdo_line_ids = array.new_line(currDay)
var cdh_line_ids = array.new_line(currDay)
var cdl_line_ids = array.new_line(currDay)

//Extend line right
nBarsForward = input.int(50)
dt = time - time[1]

//Lines calculation
var tickername = ticker.new(syminfo.prefix, syminfo.ticker)
cdo = request.security(tickername, 'D', open[0], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
cdh = request.security(tickername, 'D', high[0], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
cdl = request.security(tickername, 'D', low[0], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)

//Line Plot
if currDay > 0 and not na(cdo)
    if cdo != cdo[1] or na(cdo[1])
        //correct x2 of last line (no forward)
        line.set_x2(cdo_line, time)
        //create new lines
        cdo_line := line.new(time, cdo, time + nBarsForward * dt, cdo, xloc=xloc.bar_time, color=color.blue, width=2)
        //save ids
        array.push(cdo_line_ids, cdo_line)
        //delete lines older than N weeks
        line.delete(array.shift(cdo_line_ids))

    line.set_x2(cdo_line, time + nBarsForward * dt)
    
//Box plot
if cdo[1] != cdo
    var box cdo_box = box.new(left=bar_index, top=cdh, right=bar_index, bottom=cdl, border_color=#00000000)
    box.set_lefttop(cdo_box, left=bar_index, top=cdh)
    box.set_rightbottom(cdo_box, right=bar_index, bottom=cdl)
    box.set_bgcolor(cdo_box, color=color.rgb(0, 0, 255, 70))
```

Anybody knows how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution :

```
//Number of periods to display
box_currDay = 1

//Variables
var box cdh_box = na
var cdh_box_ids = array.new_box(box_currDay)

// Draw the box
if box_currDay > 0 and not na(cdh)
    if cdh[1] != cdh
        cdh_box := box.new(left=time, top=cdh, right=time + nbarsforward * dt, bottom=cdl, border_color=#00000000, xloc=xloc.bar_time)
        box.set_lefttop(cdh_box, left=time, top=cdh)
        box.set_rightbottom(cdh_box, right=time + nbarsforward * dt, bottom=cdl)
        box.set_bgcolor(cdh_box, color=color.rgb(0, 0, 255, 70))
        array.push(cdh_box_ids, cdh_box)
        box.delete(array.shift(cdh_box_ids))
        
    box.set_right(cdh_box, time + nbarsforward * dt)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: @Tyler2P I'd like to but I don't really understand the code myself. All I did is copying code from various sources until I achieved what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your offset input when you set the `set_rightbottom`.

Change it to:

```
box.set_rightbottom(cdo_box, right=bar_index + nBarsForward, bottom=cdl)
```